# At what addresses can UK citizens living abroad register to vote in a general election?

Tags: united-kingdom, elections

The UK is holding a general election in 34 days. I'm a UK citizen, I have previously been registered to vote in the UK several times, some of those at distinct addresses, and I have lived abroad (but still in the EU) for less than a year.

My question is: At which of my previous UK addresses can I register to vote in the upcoming election? In particular, must it be the one where I most recently lived, or the one where I was most recently registered to vote? They are not the same.

I plan to vote by proxy. Not sure if that makes a difference. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

According to the (pdf) [register-by-mail application](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/501540/Register_to_vote__overseas_voter_-_originally_resident_in_England_or_Wales_.pdf), it asks about when and where you last registered.

The main UK government website, [Register to vote](https://www.gov.uk/register-to-vote) has an online application process as well.

For either process, you will need both your National Insurance number and your passport details.